# Building Android always downloads dependencies for each build

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am using Travis CI with is connected to my github account. The builds are always successful but they take a long time as travis will keep downloading the same dependencies for each build. i.e. Downloading normally takes over 5 minutes, but building only takes less than a minute. Is there any configuration on Travis to avoid this downloading of dependencies?

Below is a snippet of what is being downloaded each time:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-3.0.0-alpha2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/dicedmelon/gradle/jacoco-android/0.1.1/jacoco-android-0.1.1.pom
Download https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.0.0-alpha2/gradle-core-3.0.0-alpha2.pom
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/groovy-all-2.4.4.pom
```

My travis.yml file:

```
language: android

jdk: oraclejdk8

env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_TARGET=android-25
    - ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a

android:
  components:
  - tools
  - platform-tools
  - build-tools-25.0.2
  - android-25
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - sys-img-${ANDROID_ABI}-${ANDROID_TARGET}

licenses:
  - android-sdk-license-.+
  - '.+'

script:
    - ./gradlew --daemon build jacocoTestReport

after_success:
    - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Part of the point of a CI is to do a clean build each time, to ensure that the software can build.  Keeping dependencies around kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: [Redownloading dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13565082/1009132) `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` is not the same than to do a [clean build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29028748/1009132) `./gradlew clean build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the cache](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) to avoid these downloads, but [it's not recommended](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/#things-not-to-cache) for Android SDK.

It's documented [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#caching) for Gradle dependencies:

> A peculiarity of dependency caching in Gradle means that to avoid
>   uploading the cache after every build you need to add the following
>   lines to your .travis.yml:

```
before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```

You can add other directories to the cache but [large files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42992699/1009132) are not recommended.